# Unable to import patch sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

after importing and installing required packages and libraries I am encountering an import error on patch_sklearn().

from sklearnx import patch_sklearn()
patch_sklearn()

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'sparse_lsqr' from 'sklearn.utils.fixes' (C:\Users\yogis\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't know what you want to do here.
But you can try this:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.image import extract_patches_2d
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to speed up the training and processing time of machine learning models using patch_sklearn(). It was working fine but suddenly showing import error

Answer (score 0):

You must install scikit learn version 1.0 and not 1.1

`pip install scikit-learn==1.0`

Then after this, restart kernel. If it doesn't work after this, I also had to force reinstall the other packages for conda.
`conda install numpy scipy joblib scikit-learn --force-reinstall`
and then restart kernel. It worked fine. This is a known bug and is fixed on pypi releases but not yet on conda.